# Xamarin Android application is not able to connect to MVC core web Api

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, exception, xamarin.forms

I am using MVC core web API for my Xamarin Android App to get http responses and my configuration is as follows:

Visual Studio version – 2022 Community edition
Android Emulator is configured to run Android 13.

The Issue I am facing is that the Android application is throwing an exception while connecting with MVC core web API.

And here is the error that I got:

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (No such host is known)'

Here is the code that I used in code behind of a button click:

```
    private async void btnRegisterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClientHandler insecureHandler = GetInsecureHandler();
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(insecureHandler);
        AppUserRegistrationModel userReg;
        AppUserRegistrationModel user = new AppUserRegistrationModel
        {
            user_fullname = entName.Text,
            user_email = entEmail.Text,
            phone_number = long.Parse(entPhoneNumber.Text),
            alternative_number = long.Parse(entPhoneNumber.Text),
            address = entAddress.Text,
            city = entCity.Text,
            district = entDistrict.Text,
            state = entState.Text,
            pincode = Int32.Parse(entPinCode.Text),
            gender_id = 1,
            aadhar_number = long.Parse(entAadharNumber.Text),
            dob = dtDOB.Date,
            blood_group_id = 2,
            registration_time = DateTime.Now,
            username = entUserName.Text,
            password = entPassword.Text,
            is_user_active = true
        };
        var userPostData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userPostData);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> msg =   httpClient.PostAsync("http://10.0.2.2:7137/api/HospitalCategoryModels", byteContent); 

        HttpResponseMessage resp = msg.Result;
        string str;
        if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Task<string> strs = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            userReg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppUserRegistrationModel>(strs.Result);
        }
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());

    }
    
    public HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
        {
            if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                return true;
            return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
        };
        return handler;
    }
```

After debugging the above code I get the input value's in the code behind but it is showing an exception at "HttpResponseMessage resp = msg.Result;". I expect the Xamarin Android Api call to enter the MVC core web API controller code.

[Android Emulator Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDhUh.png)

Comment: "No such host is known" - this sounds like a basic connectivity issue.  You need to be sure your server is reachable from your device/emulator and do some basic network debugging if it isn't

Comment: The emulator is not even able to connect to the mvc web api of my local system (localhost) , Could you please explain how to acheive it?

Comment: Is your local web server setup to alllow remote connections?

Comment: local webserver, or Local IIS is setup to allow remote connections.